# How can I download s3 bucket data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, export, metadata

I'm trying to find some way to export data from an s3 bucket such as file path, filenames, metadata tags, last modified, and file size to something like a .csv .xml or .json. Is there any way to generate this without having to manually step through and hand generate it?

Please note I'm not trying to download all the files, rather I'm trying to get at a way to export the exposed data about those files presented in the s3 console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

From [Amazon S3 Inventory - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html):

> **Amazon S3 inventory** provides comma-separated values (CSV), Apache optimized row columnar (ORC) or Apache Parquet (Parquet) output files that list your objects and their corresponding metadata on a daily or weekly basis for an S3 bucket or a shared prefix (that is, objects that have names that begin with a common string).